# How can I get the global_step in a MonitoredTrainingSession?

Tags: tensorflow, distributed-computing

I am running distributed an mnist model in distributed TensorFlow. I would like to monitor "manually" the evolution of the global_step for debugging purposes. What is the best and clean way to get the global step in a distributed TensorFlow setting?

My code below

```
 ...

with tf.device(device):
  images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name='image_input')
  labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None], name='label_input')
  data = read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir,
          one_hot=False,
          fake_data=False)
  logits = mnist.inference(images, FLAGS.hidden1, FLAGS.hidden2)
  loss = mnist.loss(logits, labels)
  loss = tf.Print(loss, [loss], message="Loss = ")
  train_op = mnist.training(loss, FLAGS.learning_rate)

hooks=[tf.train.StopAtStepHook(last_step=FLAGS.nb_steps)]

with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(
    master=target,
    is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0),
    checkpoint_dir=FLAGS.log_dir,
    hooks = hooks) as sess:


  while not sess.should_stop():
    xs, ys = data.train.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size, fake_data=False)
    sess.run([train_op], feed_dict={images:xs, labels:ys})

      global_step_value = # ... what is the clean way to get this variable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally a good practice is to initialize your global step variable in your graph-defining process, e.g. `global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, name='global_step')`. Then you can use `graph.get_tensor_by_name("global_step:0")` to get your global step easily.